# How do I fix these installation errors?

Tags: 7, installation

I'm installing D7 on Ubuntu 12.04. I've been following the procedure explained in [this](http://bhamrick.com/2011/10/19/drupal-7-on-nginx-php-postgres-on-ubuntu-11-10/) page. And this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I've already made MySQL database called 'drupaldb'.

I've also checked PHP and it's installed and it's running. I'm configuring NGINX to run D7 on it.

Please help!

Comment: certainly Your problem related to your server cofiguration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install gd library in ubuntu:

> $ sudo apt-get install php5-gd

Above command will install PHP gd library in Ubuntu.

Refer this question from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/285414/how-can-i-install-mysql-pdo-driver-in-ubuntu-10-04-and-php-5-3-2) to install mysql-pdo driver in ubuntu

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks that worked. After hours of scouring the web and this is the answer! *shakes head*

Answer (score 6):

you can install [LAMP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) in just one command

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

don't forget `^` after `lamp-server`. This will install the missing extensions and database support (LAMP was specially designed for PHP applications running on Apache server with MySQL database). After that you can place your drupal folder in `/var/www/`, and it should install smoothly after that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for PHP.

It might mean you need rebuild your PHP install, contact your server admin who should be able to enable those extensions easily